# Can't seem to find why my Prime Number Program doesn't work properly after reprompt for number

Tags: c

Im having trouble with my prime number section part of my program. When I compile and run my program, the prime numbers print out fine for the first number, but when reprompted for another number. It usually prints out either no numbers or it cuts off the prime numbers from a certain point down. Im new to coding and this forum so I'm sorry about any formatting issues in my post.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main(void)
{
    int number, n=1;
    long factorial=1;
    int a=1, b=0,c;
    int q=2, r=2, w=0;
    int prime, count;

    printf("Enter a Number:\n");
    scanf("\n%d", &number);
    while(number!=1000)
    {
        if(number<1||number>1000)
            printf("Input is Invalid\n");
        else
       {
            if(number==1000)
                printf("Goodbye\n");
            if(number<15)
            {
            factorial=number;
            n=number-1;
            while(n>=1)
            {
            factorial=factorial*n;
            n--;

            }
            printf("The Factorial of %d is: %ld\n", number,  factorial);
        }   
        c=a+b;
        printf("Fibonacci Sequence up to %d\n ", number);
        while(c<number&&a+b<number)
            {
                 c=a+b;
                 a=b;
                 b=c;
                 n++;
                 printf("%d\t", c);

                 count=n;
                 if(count%10==0)
                    printf("\n");

            }
            printf("\nTotal:%d\n", n);
            printf("\nPrime numbers up to %d:\n", number);

            while(q<=number)
            {
                prime=0;

                for(r=2;r<q;++r)
                {
                if(q%r==0)
                {
                prime=1;
                }
                }
                if(prime==0)
                {
                printf("%d\t", r);
                w++;
                }
                q++;
                }
                count=r;
                if(count%10==0)
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("\nTotal:%d\n", w);
                }
                printf("\nEnter a Number:\n");
                scanf("\n%d", &number);
                        a=1;
                b=0;                
            }
return(0);
}
```

Comment: Please indent the code properly, it looks like the last number prompt is inside the `q<=number` loop

Comment: scanf("\n%d", &number); -> Ain't this evil?

Comment: nothing from `math.h` is being utilized!  It is a poor programming practice to include header files that are not being used.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  3) consistently indent the code.  indent after every open in brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: appropriate horizontal spacing, for instance inside parens, after commas, after semicolons. around operators make the code much easier to read

Comment: variable names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  names like `a`, `b`, `c`, `n` are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: Your question talks about 'prime' numbers, but the code talks about 'Factorial' numbers and 'Fibonacci' sequence.  Which do you mean?

Comment: the code needs to pay attention to the precedence of the C operators.  Parens are an excellent method of overriding the precedence and help to clarify to the reader of the code just what is wanted.

Comment: the prompt to the user is: *Enter a Number:*  which does not indicate any restrictions on that number.  So if the user enters 40000 (valid per the prompt) then the code says: *Input is Invalid*  The user will now throw your program into the 'trash bin'.   Suggest: the prompt be: *Enter a number in the range 1...1000 inclusive*

Comment: the user will not (normally) enter a newline before entering the number. so this statement: `scanf("\n%d", &number);` would be better as: `scanf("%d", &number);`  However, when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter values) so the code should be similar to: `if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &number ) ) { perror( "scanf failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }  // implied else, scanf successful.`  Also remember that '%d" will consume leading white space, like the '\n'

Comment: the code is using an input of '1000' as an exit point, but the user is never informed of that fact.   That fact should have been part of the prompt.

Comment: the code, when the number is 1000 prints *Goodbye* but does not actually exit.

Comment: loops like: `while(n>=1)
                {
                    factorial=factorial*n;
                    n--;
                }` would be better written as: `                for( int n = number-1; n>=1; n--)
                {
                    factorial=factorial*n;
                }`  however, if using a uint64_t for 'factorial', then the limit value (currently 15)  could be expanded to a much larger value.

Comment: regarding: `for( r=2; r<q; ++r )
                {
                    if(q%r==0)
                    {
                        prime=1;
                    }
                }`  when 'prime' is set to 1, the next statement should be: 'break;` so the loop is exited early.  AND in the next 'if' statement, the value to be printed is 'q', not 'r'

Comment: in general, limiting the scope of the variables makes the code 'hold together' much better and makes it much easier to spot  the kinds of problems as was noted in the answer by jayson boubin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never resetting your variable q, which is the control variable for your prime number loop. It is best practice to create all of your variables which need to be reset inside your loop. Either reset q at the beginning/end of your loop, or create q at the beginning of your outer loop and set it to 2.

Like this:

```
while(number != 1000) {
  int q = 2;
  //other assignments below which need to be reset
  ...
  //all other code below
  ... 
}
```

Comment: ahhh thanks, that makes sense! any idea why my count variable to cut off the numbers printed per line at 10 is not working? It works for the Fibonacci sequence with the same formatting. Im guessing I'm missing something with r since I set count=r for my prime numbers?

Comment: @ryanContols It probably has something to do with the fact that your if statement that checks if your count variable is divisible by 10 isn't in the while loop that counts primes. It can be hard to see with your formatting above.

Comment: I just realized my Fibonacci sequence is also not working after the reprompt, is it for the same reasonnthe prime numbers weren't working?

Comment: ahh never mind, I forgot to reinitialize the a and b values at the end, thanks for your help

Comment: @ryancontois No problem. If you think the answer solved your problem, click the check mark to accept it. That will help keep the focus on unanswered questions.